# unexpected result in parsing nested json in qt (array does not exist)

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5

I am new in qt and I also searched in stack overflow but I can't get my answer so ***this not a duplicated post because all similar post have array [] but in this code i have not any array*** 
I want to parse this complex JSON file:

```
{
    "query": {

        "lang": "en-US",
        "results": {
            "channel": {
                "units": {
                    "distance": "mi",
                    "pressure": "in"
                },
                "ttl": "60",
                "location": {
                    "city": "city",
                    "country": "not important",
                    "region": " kkk"
                },
                "wind": {
                    "chill": "99",
                    "direction": "180",
                    "speed": "14"
                }
            }
       ...(more code)
```

i want to get chill data but out put is " " , please help me to print chill data in qt

its a part of my code:

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;

QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
QEventLoop event;
connect(response, SIGNAL(finished()), &event, SLOT(quit()));

event.exec();
json = response->readAll();

QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json.toUtf8());

QJsonObject jsonObj = doc.object();

foreach (const QJsonValue &value, jsonObj) {

      QJsonObject jsonobj = value.toObject();

      qDebug() <<  jsonobj["chill"].toString();
}
```

output of `qDebug()<<doc.object();`  is

```
D/libuntitled7.so(13258): : ** QJsonObject({"query":{"count":1,"created":"2017-07-06T21:21:16Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"channel":{"astronomy":{"sunrise":"5:48 am","sunset":"8:15 pm"},"atmosphere":{"humidity":"16","pressure":"875.0","rising":"0","visibility":"16.1"},"description":"Yahoo! Weather","image":{"height":"18","link":"http://weather.yahoo.com","title":"Yahoo! Weather","url":"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif","width":"142"},"item":{"condition":{"code":"31","date":"Fri, 07 Jul 2017 12:30 AM IRDT","temp":"85","text":"Clear"},"description":"<![CDATA[<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/31.gif\"/>\n<BR/>\n<b>Forecast:</b>\n<BR /> Fri - Sunny. High: 97Low: 78\n<BR /> Sat - Sunny. High: 100Low: 79\n<BR /> Sun - Sunny. High: 101Low: 81\n<BR /> Mon - Sunny. High: 100Low: 81\n<BR /> Tue - Mostly 
D/libuntitled7.so(13258): ..\untitled7\dialog2.cpp:84 (void Dialog2::on_pushButton_clicked()):
```

and next out put is 86

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: "unexpected result" - but where's the result?

Comment: You must share what you have tried because we will think that you have done nothing to solve your problem, and it is we do not like it in SO.

Comment: You already have 10 months in SO and therefore you should know how to ask, if you do not know you should read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: QJsonObject   jsonObj = doc.object();

Comment: code edited please say it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I comment @MohammedB.B. a way is to manually search through the keys, another way is to create a function that searches through the keys, in this case I present the second form:

```
QJsonObject findObject(QString key, QJsonObject object){
    if(object.isEmpty())
        return QJsonObject();
    if(object.keys().contains(key)){
        return object;
    }
    else{
        for(const QString& _key: object.keys()){
            if(object[_key].isObject()){
                const QJsonObject& result = findObject(key, object[_key].toObject());
                if(!result.isEmpty()){
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return QJsonObject();
}

QJsonValue findValuebyKey(QString key, QJsonDocument doc){
    QJsonObject obj_key = findObject(key, doc.object());
    return obj_key[key];
}
```

Example:

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json.toUtf8());
qDebug()<<findValuebyKey("chill", doc).toString();
```

Output:

```
"99"
```

*Note:If you generate problems the "for" enable c ++ 11, you can do this by adding `CONFIG += c++11` to your .pro*

Comment: your function is good and very thanks but i get 86 insted of 99

Comment: You can tell me what you get when you run: `qDebug()<<doc.object();   
   qDebug()<<findValuebyKey("chill", doc).toString();`

Comment: As I see you are connecting to a server, maybe the server is changing the values, so I tell you to print the complete data and then print the result of the search.

Comment: I do not see the part of `chill` in your output, you could tell me the `url` to which you are acceding please.

Comment: copy all and set to your browser

Comment: As I told you this is changing, if you want to enter the link directly and you will see that it is now 84.

Comment: That magnitude is changing so you do not get 90 but other numbers.

Comment: woow you are one of the best programmer that i see thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate in your channels array too. Easy solution:

```
const QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response->readAll().toUtf8());
// Access to "query"
const QJsonObject queryObject = doc.object();
// Access to "results"
const QJsonObject resultsObject = queryObject.value("results").toObject();
// Access to "chanels"
const QJsonObject channelsObject = resultsObject.value("channels").toObject();
// Access to "wind"
const QJsonObject windObject = channelsObject.value("wind").toObject();
// And then access to "chill"
const QJsonValue chill = windObject.value("chill");
```

Best practice its to create a recursive function to parse the JSON recursively.

Comment: thank for your replay but compiler get me error about :  const QJsonObject channelsObject = resultsObject.object(); [resultObject has no member named 'object' ]

Comment: i think your mean is const QJsonObject resultsObject = queryObject.value("chanels").toObject();   yes?

Comment: I have fixed it, thanks. I didn't compile the code =)

Comment: Ok , please explain me about qdebug() chill data i use this code to print chill data : (qDebug() << windObject["chill"].toString() << endl;) but it get me " " output why ? and how fix it ?

Comment: Sorry, i just made a little change. You have to access to the "results"  objects, next to the "channels" object, next to the "wind" object and finally to the "child" value.

Comment: Ok, i also change my code but when i want to use qdebug to print child ouput with this code ( qDebug() << chill << endl;) i just see " " result how fix it am i wrong ?

Comment: sorry eyllanesc because i'am new in qt , i use this ( `qDebug() << doc.object()["query"].toObject()["results"].toObject()["chan‌​nel"].toObject()["wi‌​nd"].toObject()["chill"];`
) but my output is (QJsonValue(null)) am i wrong ?

Comment: its get you 99 ?

Comment: Sorry but my english is not good please clearly explain me how fix out put error its very important for me